# Using AWS SDK directly in client app instead of api gateway

Tags: aws-sdk

I have one funny but strange question.
As you know we can use aws-sdk directly in react native or react js app.
It means we can execute all DynamoDB SDK commands from react native/js app.

so if table is already created in dynamodb either by console or any framework, we can use aws-sdk from client app to directly put item in dynamodb table instead of calling the api gateway & telling lambda to use aws-sdk to put item in dynamodb.

let me know what are cons for it & if this is even feasible or not.

Comment: So far I can't see any cons, except there is no throttling API with direct request generally. I even get many advantanges through this approach. Thanks to start this thread, I would like to follow this thread as well to hear more ideas.

Comment: Yes I have heard that it basically reduces the infrastructure, no lambda, no api gateway. Though it exposes table name, s3 bucket name but that's fine I think. Because even Amplify framework of AWS uses aws-exports.js file in client which has all the values. However without proper AWS IAM credentials from identitiy pools, it is impossible to access AWS resources.